# Parenting Seforim

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

Does anyone have good recommendations for a Torah-inspired parenting book? Planting & Building by Rav Wolbe was amazing and looking for other books to read next. Thanks!

Comment: Proberbs 13:24.

Comment: Dov for the win!! Thank you - that link has so many great options.